# how to add a folder containing config files to .jar META-INF -MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, xml, jar, manifest.mf, meta-inf

I want to add a folder which have the configuration files(services.XML, applicationContextClient.XML,transports.XML) for a service call, to MANIFEST.MF so that the program can read those files and read from the corresponding .properties files.
.classpath is already having an entry for this folder , this will be a manual edit to the Manifest.mf file

Comment: <classpathentry kind="src" path="props"/>

Comment: Your question is really broad.  What program are you expecting to read the manifest?  Folder, or Jar file?  If it's Jar, look at the [tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html)